# Accented characters are not indexed in Sphinx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sphinx, diacritics

I have problems with searching words that contains accented characters. I use Sphinx
 2.1.1, Linux, MsSQL 2005 via odbc (freetds).

Here is my sphinx.conf:

```
 source parentSource
 {
     type = odbc
     ...
 }

 index parentIndex
 {
     morphology = stem_en
     charset_type = utf-8
     charset_table = 0..9, a..z, A..Z->a..z, ... (mapping taken from 
     http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=charset_tables for common, A-Z)
     ...
 }
```

After changing config, I've reindexed all indexes and restarted searchd.
 When I search for "Muller" - I get results that contain only "Muller". When I search for
 "Müller" - I also get only "Muller" results. But there are also "Müller" records in db,
 that not indexed properly. Mapping for ü (U+00FC->u) present in config. I mean after
 I've added accented characters to charset_table, it (accented characters) is converted
 when I search, but not when content is indexed, as I understand.

When I run indexer with --buildstops option, I found next record in output file: "mller".
 And yes, when I search for "mller" - I get "Müller" results (but no "Muller" of course).

What I need to do for search by "Muller/Müller" give results for both "Muller" and
 "Müller"?

PS: collation used for column (and for wohle database) is SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS. I
 change column type from varchar to nvarchar, but it doesn't help. "Müller" records
 displaued properly on the site (without ???) and when I run indexer with --dump-rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the collation to `SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI` - ie: accent insensitive.

Comment: unfortunately it did not help

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?